# Max-pooling VS Sum-pooling

Tags: image, image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have <sub>partially</sub> understood Max-pooling, after reading [Convolutional Neural Networks (LeNet)](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html):

> Another important concept of CNNs is max-pooling, which is a form of
>   non-linear down-sampling. Max-pooling partitions the input image into
>   a set of non-overlapping rectangles and, for each such sub-region,
>   outputs the maximum value.

What about Sum-pooling? I couldn't find any easy to understand article.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Convolutional Neural Networks** do a great job in dealing with high dimensional data. Restricting the number of weights only to kernels weights makes learning easier due to invariance properties of images or sound. But if you look carefully at what's going on you may notice that the after first convolutional layer the dimension of your data might severely increase if you don't do the tricks like pooling.

**Max pooling** decreases the dimension of your data simply by taking only the maximum input from a fixed region of your convolutional layer. **Sum pooling** works in a similiar manner - by taking the sum of inputs instead of it's maximum.

The conceptual difference between these approaches lies in the sort of invariance which they are able to catch. **Max pooling** is sensitive to existence of some pattern in pooled region. **Sum pooling** (which is proportional to **Mean pooling**) measures the mean value of existence of a pattern in a given region.

**UPDATE:**

The subregions for **Sum pooling / Mean pooling** are set exactly the same as for **Max pooling** but instead of using **max** function you use **sum / mean**. You can read about [here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) in the paragraph about pooling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, something is still no clear; in max-pooling we select the sub-region with the max value. In sum-pooling, how do we select which sub-region to pick? Or there are no sub-regions in this case?

Comment: There are sub regions - and they are set in exactly the same manner as in max pooling case. I updated my answer.

Comment: Oh Marcin, amazing! I know got it, please check: In the right example in section **General pooling** in the link you provided, we keep 6 for the upper left subregion, since it's the max. For sum-pooling, we would keep (1+1+5+6=)13, correct?